# Change DateTime Format as "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: c#, string, datetime

This function is working fine but I return dd-MM-yyyy format but I want yyyy-MM-dd format

My input value is '13/5/2014 12:00:00 AM' I need change this format as '2014-5-13 00:00:00' but all the datetime variable is return in dd-mm-yyyy format I don't want to convert the date as string I want to store date value in datetime property with 'yyyy-MM-dd' format:

```
public DateTime DateConvertion(string Input)
{
    DateTime DateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(Input, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);            
    return DateValue;            
}
```

Comment: When it's in a `DateTime` variable (and even, if it goes into a database as a `datetime` column), it doesn't **have** a format. The "format"s that you see are what happens when you force something (such as the VS debugger or SQL database tools) to turn these values back into a *string*.

Comment: To give you another way to think about this - if your requirement was to show some value to the users, formatted in hexadecimal, would you really be trying to find a way to get an `int` variable to *store* the value formatted, or would you realise that input and output formats are *separate* from the data types that store the actual *values*?

Comment: No i mysql server is not taken is showing the error that's y i changing the format

Comment: but finally i need to store in this datetime datatype only again it change the datatype

Comment: Hello Down Voters Please Read The Question and Put Vote

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From  [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not.

You can use `dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format instead. Here an example;

```
string s = "13/5/2014 12:00:00 AM";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

`DateTime` has no implicit format, it is just a `DateTime` value. You can format it as `string` with `DateTime.ToString()` method like;

```
date.ToString("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Take a look at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: You have this link in browser shortcut :)

Comment: I dont Want the String i need only datetime variable

Comment: what is Dump how to help That method to me please tel me friend

Comment: @Dinesh What do you mean? But your `Input` is `string` in your method definition.

Comment: Yes but i want output in datetime format with yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: Please Some one Help me

Comment: @Dinesh `DateTime` doesn't have any format. If you have already a `DateTime`, you can format it's string representation with `DateTime.ToString(format)` method as well.

Comment: No friend i need to direct pass the object and create some mysql query dynamically for that i need to use datetime variable with mysql format

Comment: @Dinesh Then create an `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`. Execute your command with `ExecuteReader` (or maybe `ExecuteScalar` (depends on your query)). Get your value with specify your column name. Then format your `DateTime` with `.ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string DateConvertion(string Input)
{
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(Input, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would print todays date in that format

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Comment: The OP is interested about parsing a specially formatted date string to a DateTime. In your response you do it in the other way around. Please revise your post.